# explain in much more details for well ordering principle, proof from Munkres

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> [image]

Here is proof from Munkres' Topology, generally I could understand it employ the induction to prove the well ordering theorem, but where I highlighted, I don't catch up its logic.

Can anyone fill in more details about what Munkres' said?

1. How come that n+1 will be the smallest element, otherwise so what the intersection is non-empty.
2. How does it conclude $A=\mathbb{Z_+}$

Appreciated for any more details explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is by induction, and induction is applied to the set:

> $A = \{ n \in \mathbb Z_+ \mid \text { the property of the theorem holds } \}$.

Obviously, $A \subseteq \mathbb Z_+$; thus, to show that "the property" holds for $\mathbb Z_+$, we have to prove the other inclusion: $\mathbb Z_+ \subseteq A$.

This is done in usual two-steps proof: (i) $1 \in A$, and (ii) if $n \in A$, then $n+1 \in A$.

Thus, for (ii), we **assume** that $n \in A$ and we consider a subset $C$ whatever of $\{ 1, \ldots, n+1 \}$.

We have two cases:

either (a) $C = \{ n+1 \}$ or (b) not.

If (a), then $C$ has a smallest element (it has only one).

If (b), we have that $C$, irrespective of the fact that $n+1 \in C$ or not, we have some number $k \ne n+1$ that belongs to $C$ (because either $C$ has again one single element, in which case it is not $n+1$ or has more than one element, and thus necessarily one of them is different from $n+1$).

But if $k \ne n+1$, due to the fact that $C$ is a subset of $\{ 1, \ldots, n+1 \}$, we have that $k \le n$, and thus $C \cap \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ is not-empty.

But $C \cap \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ is a not-empty subset of $\{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, and we have assumed that "the property" holds up to $n$.

Thus, it has a smallest element, and this element is also the smallest element of $C$. Why? Because $C$, in case (b), can have at most one element "outside" $\{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, i.e. $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I 've read your comment over and over again, and still have two tiny points that bug me. 1. know that that for inductive process, we need to varify the $1\in A$ but why do we need to point out (i) $C=\{n+1\}$ has a smallest element when it's already the subset of $A$  2.  When $C$ is the subset of $A$ with elements $k\leq n$, what if it excludes the ${n+1}$ all the time, then how can I convince myself it is inductive.      Looking for your reply

Comment: @LJNG - in the inductive step we assume that the property holds for subsets of $\{ 1, \ldots, n \}$; thus, there is no $n+1$ yet.

Comment: Thank you for your relpy. If there is no chance for $C$ to have the element $n+1$, how can we generalise it to be  inductive? I might misunderstand somthing.  I thought $C$ is the subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ with at most elements $k\leq n$, I thought this intended claim whatever the $C$ is,  e.g the set $\{2,3,4\dots,n+1\}$ with this $n$ elements also has the least element. How can I convince myself such $n+1$ is comparable (e.g Is that possible for the "new entry" element be the least elements)

Comment: @LJNG - no clear at all. We have to prove the **property**: "every non-empty subset of $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ has a smallest element". We prove that every subset of $\{ 1 \}$ has the property. We assume that the property holds for $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}$ and we have to prove that it holds also for $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n, n+1 \}$. It's Ok up to now?

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am consufing the part it's also holds for $\{1,2,3,\dots,n,n+1\}$. $C$ with $k\leq n $ of the subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n,n+1\}$ has the least element, when $n+1$ not in $C$ that's totally fine. However, since $C$ is the subset of  $\{1,2,3,\dots,n,n+1\}$, so it could have a chance the element $n+1\in C$ and also only has at most $n$ elements, then I am hard to convince myself that $n+1$ in the $C$ is comparable, and if it possible that $n+1$ could be the least?

Comment: @LJNG - Ok. Property holds for $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n \}$. Let $C \subseteq \{ 1,2, \ldots, n, n+1 \}$ and consider two cases: (i) $C= \{ n+1 \}$ (it is a subset of $\{ 1,2, \ldots, n, n+1 \}$: do you agree?) and it has a least element: $n+1$ or (ii) $C \ne  \{ n+1 \}$. What does it mean? that in $C$ we have some other element $k \ne n+1$. Do you agree?

Comment: Now, we have several possibilities: $C$ can have only one element (obviously $\le n$) or can be the "full"  $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$... In all cases it includes some number of  $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ and thus $C \cap  \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \} \ne \emptyset$. Do you agree? This means that $C \cap  \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ is a not-empty subset of $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ and we can apply the inductive hypotheses.

Comment: The final step is to convince yourself that the smallest element of $C \cap  \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$ is also the smallest of $C$.

Comment: "since C is the subset of {1,2,3,…,n,n+1}, so it could have a chance the element n+1∈C and also only has at most n elements, then I am hard to convince myself that n+1 in the C is comparable, and if it possible that n+1 could be the least?" The tow cases are: only $n+1 \in C$ or not. If not, $C$ can have from $1$ to $n+1$ elements: it can be the "full $\{ 1, ... n+1 \}$ but in this case the inetersection with $\{ 1, ... n \}$ will rule out $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I agree with most of parts you said, in one of your response, you claim $C$  has "full length" $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, but in the last repsonse, $C$ can have from $1$ to $n+1$. Isn't $C$ should only have at most $n$ elements, because we intended to use that " hold up for $n$ property".